# Android device not entering deep doze

Tags: android, adb, android-doze

I am trying to force my device (Redmi S2) running MIUI into deep doze using ADB commands but it doesn't seem to work.

After running

```
adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
```

I can go into light doze by using:

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step light
Stepped to light: IDLE

adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle light
Now forced in to light idle mode
```

But if I try to enter deep doze, it doesn't work:

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step deep
Stepped to deep: INACTIVE

adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle deep
Unable to go deep idle; stopped at INACTIVE
```

Using only

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step
```

returns the same output

```
Stepped to deep: INACTIVE
```

Any suggestions how to overcome this?

Comment: Having the same issue on a Pixel 2 running Android Q Beta 6.

Comment: @Flyview After looking at the logs, I noticed that it is an issue with Alarm Manager not recognizing the alarm listener. For example, change the `light_after_inactive_to`, `light_pre_idle_to`, `inactive_to` to 0 and turn off the screen. The phone would constantly be trying to go to deep doze and logcat would be spammed with "Unrecognized alarm listener". So it seems to be a bug within the ROM.